# aniamte inputview left to right border bottom

Tags: swift

I have created this width animation which creates a border-bottom for my TextField and I want to animate it so that when the user clicks on the TextField the CALayer goes from left to right and then appear. the problem is that the animation start from the center and then the width grows to each side while I want it to start from left to right... What am I missing ?

[image]

```
override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
    let shape = CALayer()
    shape.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.height, width: self.width, height: 1)
    shape.frame.origin.x = 0
    shape.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
    
    let boundsAnim:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
         boundsAnim.fromValue = 0
        boundsAnim.toValue = self.width
        boundsAnim.duration = 2

         shape.add(boundsAnim, forKey: "bounds.size.width")
       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the anchor point to the left side

```
shape.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
```

Comment: i did that but now it starts from beginning but can't see the full width please check the screenshot i updated it on post

Comment: Hmm... try also setting the position too: `shape.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`

Comment: yeah, I figured that out already thank you... so this basically overrides the cgRect i created earlier? i

Comment: Pretty much -- the frame is calculated from the `position`, `anchorPoint`, and `bounds`. When you changed the anchor point, the position got changed, so you need to change it back.